# In HTML, the formatting is all messed up

Tags: html, formatting

Here is the code:

```
    <html>

<head>
<title> ATS Business and Games - Home </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formatting.css"/">
<meta name= "description" content="This page has our rules along with links to our external and internal download pages.">
<meta name="keywords" content="ATS ats business and games video tutorials video videos tutorial minecraft">
</head>
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<body>

<a href="http://atsbusinessandgames.co.cc">
<div class="toper" align="top">
<p style="color:white"> ATS Business and Games <img align="right"
src="http://atsbusinessandgames.co.cc/pictures/business-logo-small-with-tag-line.GIF" alt="ATS Business and Games Logo with tag line" 
                                            width=115px height=100px> </p>
</div>
</a>
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<div class="navt">
<p style="text-align:center;color:white"> <a href="http://atsbusinessandgames.co.cc/">Home</a>

</div>
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<p> <span><b><font  size="5" color="black"><h1>Rules for Downloads</h1></b></font>
<font size="4" color="black">Please note that this section is here to protect both us and you. 
Proceeding to any download page beyond this assumes that you have read and understood all these rules.
If you have any questions then you may contact us (the link can be found at the bottom of every page).


<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<div class="bottom" align="bottom">
<p style="text-align:center;color:white"> Copyright (C) 2011
<a href="mailto:info@atsbusinessandgames.co.cc?subject=Information Request&body=What information would you like. We will try and get to you as soon
as possible!%0A%0A">Contact Us</a> </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So you can see how the formatting looks here is the link to the page:
http://www.atsbusinessandgames.co.cc/Downloads

and here is what the formatting of the page should look like:

http://www.atsbusinessandgames.co.cc/

Can someone please tell me how I can fix the formatting?

---

**Note: I am working on the page so the body code may look a little different (as in more paragraphs). If I make any major changes I'll post them here otherwise right click then left click on view source.**

Comment: are you comfortable with Div tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to `../formatting.css` instead of `formatting.css` in the Downloads part.

Also, there is a `"` at the end which shouldn't be there, but I don't think it's a problem for any browsers

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../formatting.css"/>
```

Comment: if there was another sub-directory would I have to put "../../". I'm asumming that ".." is a wildcard. I haven't worked with relative locations before. I have always used exsact locations.

Comment: ../ points to the folder above the current folder.
so if you refer to ../../test.css in blie/bloe/bla/index.html, you are refering to blie/bloe/bla/../../test.css, which is the same as blie/test.css. You can even try this in your browser: go to http://www.atsbusinessandgames.co.cc/folder/folder2/../../formatting.css